Bitwise operation in HQL
I am using Hibernate 6, and I have created a custom dialect.
Below is my CustomPostgreSQLDialect.java:
public class CustomPostgreSQLDialect extends Dialect {

    @Override
    public void contributeTypes(TypeContributions typeContributions,
                                ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) {
        super.contributeTypes(typeContributions, serviceRegistry);
    }

    @Override
    public void initializeFunctionRegistry(FunctionContributions functionContributions) {
        super.initializeFunctionRegistry(functionContributions);
        functionContributions
            .getFunctionRegistry()
            .register("bitwise_and", new StandardSQLFunction("bitwise_and(?1 & ?2)", StandardBasicTypes.INTEGER));
    }
}

Below is the method in the repository. I have used the bit_and function inside it:
public List<UserPermissions> getUsersWithoutReadPermissionCustomDialect() {
    return find("bitwise_and(permissions,1)=0").list();
}

But I am getting the following error:
JDBC exception executing SQL [ select u1_0.id,u1_0.permissionValues,u1_0.permissions,u1_0.username from user_permissions u1_0 where bitwise_and(?1 & ?2)(u1_0.permissions,1)=0 ] [No value specified for parameter 1.]
I have to perform the following query:
SELECT user
    FROM user_permissions
    WHERE (permissions & 1) = 0;

It should provide a list of users not having read permissions. 1 is the key for the "READ" permission.

Looking at the generated SQL bitwise_and(?1 & ?2)(u1_0.permissions,1)=0 looks very suspicious. You probably need to replace
new StandardSQLFunction("bitwise_and(?1 & ?2)", StandardBasicTypes.INTEGER)

with
new StandardSQLFunction("bitwise_and", StandardBasicTypes.INTEGER)

(?1 & ?2) seems wrong at that place since this is a function registration and not an actual function usage.

Didn't work out now getting below error :
JDBC exception executing SQL [select u1_0.id,u1_0.permissionValues,u1_0.permissions,u1_0.username from user_permissions u1_0 where bitwise_and(u1_0.permissions,1)=0] [ERROR: function bitwise_and(integer, integer) does not exist\n  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

As per Hibernate 6 we have a predefined "bitand" function in CommonFuntionFactory, how can we use that method If my customDialect if extending PostgreSqlDialect class.
